# Java copy file to folder with access permission

Tags: java, permissions, copy

Is it possible to copy a file belonging to one user and copy it to a folder belonging to another user in java?

Comment: it depends. If it is possible in the shell, it'll be possible in java. What did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, if the machine's access controls permit the particular process to do so.  That's substantially independent of the the implementation of the process -- *i.e.* whether Java is used doesn't really factor in.

Comment: i want do this from the java code but the folder has  permission . I don't write i do it in linux system

Answer (score 0):

Per John Bollinger:

"Yes, if the machine's access controls permit the particular process to do so. That's substantially independent of the the implementation of the process -- i.e. whether Java is used doesn't really factor in."